# What parameters can React.createElement() take in?

Tags: reactjs

For instance, this code snippet:

```
React.createElement(
  "h1",
  null,
  "Shopping List for ",
  props.name
),
```

What does the null value represent, or what can it be used for?

Comment: Not sure why you got the downvote (maybe because use of createElement() is discouraged in favor of JSX). Anyway, the second argument is an object containing properties ('props' in React terms) that get passed to the component. From here: https://learn.co/lessons/react-create-element

Comment: "This question does not show any research effort" – the answer is in the official documentation and API.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [the React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement):

> #### `createElement()`
>
> ```
> React.createElement(
>   type,
>   [props],
>   [...children]
> )
> ```
>
> Create and return a new React element of the given type. The type argument can be either a tag name string (such as `'div'` or `'span'`), a React component type (a class or a function), or a React fragment type.

What the docs don’t explicitly mention is that `props` should be an object. For example:

```js
{
  click: dothing,
  className: 'myClass'
}
```

It may be `{}` or `null` if you need to specify children but not properties